# toggige-arrow.jpg закодированная картинка на взломанном сайте

Tags: php, криптография, decrypt

Появился на сайте странный файл (сайт взломали) `toggige-arrow.jpg`. Внутри соответственно не картинка, код тот что ниже, стал гуглить, информации не  нашел. При строгом поиске по названию картинки находит такие же файлы на других сайтах, но результатов не много (6 страниц). У файлов одинаковая структура, 32 первых символа, текстовый смайлик, и дальше длинная строка по виду напоминающая что то закодированное в `base64`, но декодирование осмысленного результата не дает (или я его не понимаю и скорее всего это не оно), а может и кодированная строка и ключ...

Сайт на PHP по этому думаю что и с содержимым можно сделать с его помощью. Знаю вопрос очень абстрактный, но не кидайтесь помидорками сразу)) Может быть кто-то сталкивался с таким?

Целиком файлы выкинул в [яндекс облако](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/KX0CrXMJKWvysg), один мой и еще два из тех что нагуглил.

```
dacf2f49680fb4429bcfd4a5fbe2b001|{-.-!!!}|CQ9jnUNt...=

|{-.-!!!}|CQ9jnUNt - общая часть
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогу это все выглядит примерно вот так:

```
$raw = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . 'toggige-arrow.jpg');
$encoded = explode('|{-.-!!!}|', $raw);
$decoded = base64_decode(str_rot13($encoded[1]));

$encoded[0] == md5($decoded); // true
```

`$decoded` содержит абусифицированный PHP скрипт.